# Filter files based on file name

Tags: python, file, os.walk

I have a folder that has 4 different kinds of file. For example:

Type 1:  `00001_a.png`

Type 2:  `00231_b.mat`

Type 3:  `00001_c.jpg`

Type 4:  `00001_c.png`

How can I filter these files into 4 lists? My current solution can only filter based on file extension.

```
all_file = os.walk(input_path).next()[2] #get files only
list_one = [ fi for fi in all_file if fi.endswith("*.png") ] # "*_a.png" won't work
```

Comment: you need to use glob.

Comment: Can you explain how you are trying to partition them? Is it by both the `_<letter>` part, and the file extension?

Comment: You can try also `list_one = [ fi for fi in all_file if fi.find("_a.png") > -1 ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just omit the asterisk (`*`) in `endswith()` and it will work as expected, e.g. `fi.endswith('_a.png')`.

Proposed better solution which avoids hard-coding the supported types:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def get_file_type(filename):
    base, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    return base.rsplit('_', 1)[1] + ext

files_by_type = defaultdict(list)
for filename in os.listdir(input_path):
    filetype = get_file_type(filename)
    files_by_type[filetype].append(filename)
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider a regex solution using `os` module's list directory:

```
import os, re

# CURRENT DIRECTORY OF RUNNING SCRIPT (OR MANUALLY ENTER PATH)
cd = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

a_pngfiles = [file for file in os.listdir(cd) if re.match("^.*_a.png$", file)]
b_matfiles = [file for file in os.listdir(cd) if re.match("^.*_b.mat$", file)]
c_jpgfiles = [file for file in os.listdir(cd) if re.match("^.*_c.jpg$", file)]
c_pngfiles = [file for file in os.listdir(cd) if re.match("^.*_c.png$", file)]
```